# How can I get rid of an UnHandledException while playing with TextBox and SIP control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox

In my case, I have a TextBox and two buttons Button1 and Button2. Here is how I am doing..

```
private void Button1_click()
{
   TextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
}

private void Button2_click()
{
   TextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
   this.Focus()
}
```

Now the flow, what I am doing...

1. Program loads, I click on the TextBox, the SIP appears and I click somewhere on the screen the keyboard disappears.
2. I press Button2 and the TextBox becomes read only and the SIP disappears (if it was shown)
3. I tap on the TextBox (while it is still in the read only mode)
4. I press Button1, and click on the TextBox.. BOOOMM.. the program crashes with an UnHandledException.

...

I have tried gotfocus() and LostFocus of TextBox but nothing seems to help, Just before crashing, the GotFocus of the TextBox is NOT called. I tap on the textBox and suddenly it crashes.

Really trying to figure out what could be wring for the last 9 hours (oh yeah, I am dumb programmer :)

Could anyone please put some light on the problem and tell me any possible solution?

Thanks very much :)

Comment: What happens if you wrap your code with try/catch blocks?

Comment: Could you give us the type of exception, and the full callstack?

Comment: Nothing... the error still appears. As I mentioned that it doesn't even go inside the code block.

Comment: What is the exception that you get? And just to make it clear, you are able to press button1 and it's fine but when you click on the textbox after is when it crashes, correct?

Comment: > IQ.dll!iq_main.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 110 + 0x5 bytes C#
  System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e) + 0x30 bytes 
  System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.Error.GetXresultForUserException(System.Exception ex) + 0x4d bytes 
  System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName) + 0x125 bytes 
  [External Code]

Comment: @banging: that's right, when I press the button it is ok, only when I press tap on the textbox then the exception is raised

Comment: Then it's clear it's one of the textbox events that's causing this and not any of the buttons you posted. Please check and post the relevant textbox events that you're handling.

Comment: TextBox_LostFocus, TextBox_KeyDown, TextBox_GotFocus... Apart from these, I used TextBox_TextChnaged, TextBox_KeyUp but not anymore.

Comment: One of these is causing your problems. So if you can't debug by yourself (give it a good hard try) then update your question with the relevant code. What you have posted here is useless.

Comment: The code is too much, also it is confidential. I can share with one or two but not in a public. How can I do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11691/discussion-between-saafh-and-banging)

Comment: Basic debugging strategy: create a new project, with a textbox and two buttons. Then add the logic until you can reproduce the problem (or the other way around: remove the logic from your main project until you can't reproduce the problem anymore)

Comment: So you don't want to help yourself or even TRY? Then pay someone to do it.

Comment: Thanks KooKiz for the tip, it is working on a new Project.

Comment: I have been helping myself for hours already :), I still don't know what is wrong in that project, Everything seems to be OK. Even Debugging steps don't seem to help to know from where the exception is being raised.

Comment: please post a full repro. and then read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints before asking your next question

Comment: @MattLacey: Sorry if you get bothered by the language of the question. English is not my mother tongue, nor I speak good english. I shall perhaps read the article when my problem will get solved, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working really hard on this issue, I finally used two separate textBoxes and set the visibility true/false on the button clicks.

I removed all the events of the TextBox, I simplified the code (properties values and events) to as much extent as possible but the code was crashing.

One thing I noticed though,

As in the 4th point in my questions, I clicked on the Button1, then on the textBox and it was crashing. But when I did it like "press Button1, **click anywhere on the screen**, and then clicking the TextBox didn't crash)

Strange!